# How to mock a static method of third class called in second class using Junit/mockito?

Tags: junit, static, mockito

I am writing test case of following method

```
class BeanDefinitions {
    public Customizer<ReactiveResilience4JCircuitBreakerFactory> apiEnrichmentLayerCircuitBreakerCustomizer(
            final HttpClientConfigurationProperties clientsConfig
    ) {
        return CircuitBreakerCustomizers.fromHttpClientConfig(
                API_ENRICHMENT_LAYER_CLIENT_ID,
                clientsConfig.getHttpClients().get(API_ENRICHMENT_LAYER_CLIENT_ID)
        );
    }
}
```

I want to mock the static method (CircuitBreakerCustomizers.fromHttpClientConfig) which is called in that class.(dont want to run that static method but when that static.method call then return something)

```
Assertions.assertNotNull(beanDefinitions.apiEnrichmentLayerCircuitBreakerCustomizer(clientsConfig));
```

I always get NPE as static method is performing some task which i don't want to execute.

Is there any possibility in mockito to achieve the same i.e mock inner static method?

Answer (score 0):

Possible duplicate of [Mocking static methods with Mockito](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21105403/mocking-static-methods-with-mockito).

You can mock static methods with latest Mockito using `mockito-inline`. For your case, it can be done in the following way:

```java
@Test
void someTest() {
    var customizersStaticMock = Mockito.mockStatic(CircuitBreakerCustomizers.class);
    customizersStaticMock.when(() -> CircuitBreakerCustomizers.fromHttpClientConfig(Mockito.any(), Mockito.any())).thenReturn(someCustomizer);
}
```